# How to customize properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, defineproperty

How do I get TypeScript to emit property definitions such as:

```
Object.defineProperties(this, {
    view: {
        value: view,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false,
        configurable: false
    },
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was looking for exactly the same thing when I stumbled upon [TypeScript Handbook: Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). In "Method Decorators" paragraph they define `@enumerable` decorator factory, which looks like this (I'm simply copy-pasting from there):

```
function enumerable(value: boolean) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        descriptor.enumerable = value;
    };
}
```

and they use it like this:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }

    @enumerable(false)
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

So another way of addressing it, is through usage of decorators.

**PS:**
This feature requires `experimentalDecorators` flag to be passed to `tsc`or set in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `get` and `set` in TypeScript, which compile into `Object.defineProperties`.

This is an ECMAScript 5 feature, so you can't use it if you are targeting ES3 (the default for the compiler). If you are happy to target ES5, add `--target ES5` to your command.

TypeScript:

```
class MyClass {
    private view;
    get View() { return this.view; }
    set View(value) { this.view = value }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() { }
    Object.defineProperty(MyClass.prototype, "View", {
        get: function () {
            return this.view;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this.view = value;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return MyClass;
})();
```

But if you want full control of setting enumerable and configurable - you could still use the raw `Object.defineProperties` code.

Comment: Ok... but how do you handle something like:

`describe('MyComponent', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
      value: jest.fn(() => {
        return {matches: true};
      })
    });
  });
});`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently supported if you want all the properties to be emitted like that. I'd recommend filing an issue at the [CodePlex site](http://typescript.codeplex.com/) with details about what your use case and requirements are.

If you do compile with --target ES5, you can have something like this:

```
class n {
    get foo() { return 3; }
    bar() { return 5; }
}
```

Which produces this code:

```
var n = (function () {
    function n() { }
    Object.defineProperty(n.prototype, "foo", {
        get: function () {
            return 3;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    n.prototype.bar = function () {
        return 5;
    };
    return n;
})();
```

Comment: yeah, i'm looking for a way to customize the 'enumerable', 'configurable' and 'writable' attributes to match my existing code.