# Typescript property does not exist on type {}

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code in **Typescript**. Why does the compiler throws an error?

```
var object = {};
Object.defineProperty(object, 'first', {
     value: 37,
     writable: false,
     enumerable: true,
     configurable: true
});
console.log('first property: ' + object.first);
```

> js.ts(14,42): error TS2339: Property 'first' does not exist on type
>   '{}'.

It's the same code snippet like in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) of mozilla (examples section).

Comment: Why would you need Object.defineProperty at all? Whydont just make it `readonly` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way is to do interface, so compiler will know that property exists.

```
interface IFirst{
  first:number;
}


let object = {} as IFirst;
Object.defineProperty(object, 'first', {
  value: 37,
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
console.log('first property: ' + object.first);
```

Take a look at this question [How to customize properties in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696250/how-to-customize-properties-in-typescript)

Comment: It works fine. But is this the propper way to do it? ps: first should be of type number in your interface

Comment: I think the line `let object = {} as IFirst;` will throw error cause the `first` property is required and missed in the type

Comment: `const CONFIG_CACHE = {} as Config` works great... it's a shame such a small change isn't suggested in the hints. I now get t he reasoning of why `const CONFIG_CACHE: Config = {} ` doesn't work in hindsight.

Answer (score 7):

Make the object type **any**:

```
var object: any = {};
```

Comment: Turning off type guards kinda defeats the purpose of using TypeScript.

Comment: strange answer, which I hope no one will use. Disabling typing usually leads to typing errors later on that you won't even notice.

Comment: there is no one size fit all... and i'm sure the OP can decide for themselves if they want the gaurd or not

Answer (score 0):

That's because Typescript is a strict type language. When you create a variable and give to it a type, you can't access properties that does not exists in that type. After adding extra property will not force the compiler to look for it. If you need to add a property after the creation, make the type of your variable `any`.

Comment: Better to add an index signature `[k: string]: any` to the type instead of disabling all validation and all intellisense.