# Angular 5/Typescript Property 'propName' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to create a Typescript function that returns an object. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR in src\app\components\model\model.component.html(3,30): : Property 'heading' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

My function looks like this:

```
getTestObject(): { [key: string]: any } {
    let myObj = {};

    myObj = {
        'heading': 'My heading',
        /* Other properties here */
    };

    return myObj;
}
```

Then I use it in my html file like this: `{{ myObj.heading }}`. I was reading the answer over here: [Typescript property does not exist on type {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467069/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-type) and changed the following line:

```
let myObj = {};
```

changed to:

```
let myObj = {} as { [key: string]: any };
```

but I get the same error. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Not sure will it work or not, but try `let myObj: { [key: string]: any } = {};`

Comment: Are u sure myObj is accessible in your template?.. because i see it declared as let inside the function.

Comment: why don't you do `myObj.heading = 'My heading'` ?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Unfortunately, it didn't work that way either.
@FranklinPious I have a variable called `myObj` outside of the function as well which I assign by calling that function. Sorry should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to ensure you are calling the function getTestObject() while your view of your component is loading.

I was able to get this to work with a simpler verison of the getTestObject() function and a class member defined as
 `myObj:any = {}`

here my Class below

```
export class MySampleClass{
    myobj:any={};
    getTestObject(){
        this.myobj = {heading:'My heading'};
        return this.myobj;
    }
    void ngOnInit() {
        this.getTestObject();
    }
}
```

And here's my template interpolation

```
{{ myObj.heading }}
```

Comment: This worked, I had to forgot to assign a type to `myobj` outside of the function. I only had `myobj = {}`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've test your code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and it works.

```
function getTestObject(): { [key: string]: any } {
  let myObj = {};

  myObj = {
    'heading': 'Works !!'
    /* Other properties here */
  };

  return myObj;
}

let a = getTestObject();
console.log(a.heading);
```