# Angular 7 - HttpClient "Property 'success' does not exist on type Object"

Tags: angular, typescript

When someone registers, I post the info to my back-end. When successfully registering a user, I get a json response back of {success: true, msg: "User registered"}. My problem is when I try to do an if statement to check if success is set to true.

**Here is my code that isn't working:**

```
    // Register User
    this.apiService.registerUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      if(data.success) {
        this.flashMessage.show('Registration successful', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3200 });
      } else {
        this.flashMessage.show('Registration failed', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3200 });
      }
    });
```

---

**I was able to console.log the response of data, and it returned:**

```
{success: true, msg: "User registered"}
```

---

**Here is the code from my ApiService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from '../models/User';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  private baseUri: string = 'http://localhost:5000/api';
  private headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUri + '/register', user, { headers: this.headers });
  }
}
```

---

**Here is the code from my Register Component:**

```
onRegisterSubmit() {
    const user: User = {
      firstName: this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName,
      email: this.email,
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    };

// Register User
    this.apiService.registerUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });

  }
```

[Screenshot of error from ng serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rCBR.png)

I'm quite new to working with angular let alone a back-end, so if you could explain why this error was occurring it would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: can you post the actual error stack? does it happen at runtime, or compile time?

Comment: is `success` a result of what's being returned from the `POST`, or are you trying to access something on the `HttpResponse` itself?

Comment: `success` is a result of what's being returned from the `POST`. Here is a screenshot of the console error https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rCBR.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324949/error-ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y)

Comment: I overcome this issue by Identifying the type of `res` as `any`. So it should be like this: 

`this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api', obj).subscribe((res:any) => { console.log(res.success) }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a compiler error, and it's one of the reasons Typescript is awesome!

Your `registerUser` method's return type is implicitly an `Object` (or `{}`) because that's what `http.post` is returning. `http.post` accepts a generic parameter to define what will be coming back in the response's `body`. Without that parameter, it will return type `{}` (because, without some sort of definition, JSON is just an unknown `Object`)... and a key of `success` does not exist on `{}`.

Assuming you have a fleshed out response object, just strongly type it:

```
interface UserPostResponse {
  success: boolean
}

...

  registerUser(user: User): Observable<UserPostResponse> {
    return this.http.post<UserPostResponse>(this.baseUri + '/register', user, { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

Conversely, if you wanted the `HttpRequest` itself and not the body, you just have to tell the `HttpClient` what part of the response to observe:

```
  registerUser(user: User): Observable<HttpResponse<object>> {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUri + '/register', user, { headers: this.headers }, observe: 'response');
  }
```

...and `HttpResponse` has a `status`, `statusText`, `body`, etc.

Comment: Wa about to post the same thing about HttpClient.post generics https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-post-generics?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much. I have been trying to find my way around this for close to 2 weeks now haha. Thank you too @WilliamLohan for the stackblitz.

Answer (score 4):

Property '*success*' does not exist on type '*Object*'. Create code as:

```js
// Register User
this.apiService.registerUser(user).subscribe( (data) => {
    if(data['success']) {
        this.flashMessage.show('Registration successful', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3200 });
    } else {
        this.flashMessage.show('Registration failed', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3200 });
    }
});
```

This change correct my error in Angular *ts* file.

Answer (score 1):

> error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'

Is compile time error. Angular `HttpClient` has various `post` function declarations, one of which is:

```
post<T>(url: string, body: any | null, options?: { ... }): Observable<T>;
```

Where you can strongly type your type of response. You can introduce response interface and use it like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { User } from '../models/User';

export interface RegisterResponse {
  success: boolean;
  msg: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  private baseUri: string = 'http://localhost:5000/api';
  private headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(user: User): Observable<RegisterResponse> {
    return this.http.post<RegisterResponse>(this.baseUri + '/register', user, { headers: this.headers });
  }
}
```

Then you will be type safe from TypeScript compiler perspective.

Otherwise, matched declaration will be:

```
post(url: string, body: any | null, options?: { ... }): Observable<Object>;
```

Where `Object` has no declared property `succuess`, thus will cause that error.

Another way to avoid it is to use `as any` or `any`, see references below. But normally, you would want TypeScript to track your types.

TypeScript is strongly typed, meaning that it will attempt to make sure that data types your are using are actually correct. So if you are trying to refer to some property which has no known type, it will complain.

You may see also:

- [error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324949/error-ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y)
- [Ignore Typescript Errors “property does not exist on value of type”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type)
- [Typescript property does not exist on type {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467069/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-type)

And so on to understand the matter.

Comment: Wa about to post the same thing about HttpClient.post generics https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-post-generics?file=src/app/app.component.ts